# How do I read a text file located in the same directory as my index.html using XMLHttpRequest() without using <input type="file" id="fileToLoad">

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I have my index.html and in the same directory I have a text file that I put there and want to be able to read it. Everything I have tried has failed except when using the input type format. I don't need to do a file selection. I know what the file is and where it is.

Here is my function:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementById("FunText").innerHTML = 
    "The text should show here:" + readTextFile('file:///E:/My_Html/list.txt');

    function readTextFile(file)
    {
      var allText = "";
      var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
      rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
      rawFile.onreadystatechange = function()
           {
            if(rawFile.readyState == 4)
               {
                if(rawFile.status == 200 || rawFile.status == 0) // status = 0
                   {
                    allText = rawFile.responseText;
                    alert("I get this:" + allText);
                   }
                }
          }
          rawFile.send(null);
      }
```

The variable allText always comes back empty. If I put "file:///E:/My_Html/list.txt" in the browser search box and it displays the contents of the file. Does anyone see the problem? I have tried rawFile.send(null), rawFile.send(), immediately after the open, at the end of the function. Nothing works. I have searched Stackoverflow, W3, and others. I am at a loss for ideas.
Thank you for your patience and time.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the **JQuery** library to your project and use the `$.get()` function:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Example (as the file is in the same level as the index.html):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    function readTextFile(file) {
        $.get(file, function(data) {
            document.getElementById("FunText").innerHTML = "The text should show here: " + data;
        });
    }

    readTextFile("list.txt");

</script>
```